# Como conseguir uma lista a partir de um JSON

Tags: javascript, json

Estou tentando fazer uma lista de moedas a partir de um texto JSON, para isso estou utilizando a API  "exchangeratesapi.io".

Utilizando JavaScript eu consegui certo sucesso:

```js
const url = 'https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?base=USD'

fetch(url)
  .then(result => result.json())
  .then(json => console.log(json.rates))
```

Porém eu gostaria de criar uma lista com somente os nomes abreviados das moedas, por exemplo:

```
{
  BGN,
  NZD,
  ILS,
  RUB,
  CAD,
  USD,
  PHP,
  CHF,
  AUD,
  JPY,
  TRY,
  HKD,
  MYR,
  HRK,
  CZK,
  IDR,
  DKK,
  NOK,
  HUF,
  GBP,
  MXN,
  THB,
  ISK,
  ZAR,
  BRL,
  SGD,
  PLN,
  INR,
  KRW,
  RON,
  CNY,
  SEK,
  EUR 
}
```

Ou até mesmo criar um array contendo todas elas a partir disso, por exemplo:

```
let currency = ["BGN", "NZD", "ILS", "RUB", "CAD", "USD", "PHP", "CHF", "AUD", "JPY", "TRY", "HKD", "MYR", "HRK", "CZK", "IDR", "DKK", "NOK", "HUF", "GBP", "MXN", "THB", "ISK", "ZAR", "BRL", "SGD", "PLN", "INR", "KRW", "RON", "CNY", "SEK", "EUR"];
```

**Quais tecnologias ou métodos devo utilizar para conseguir isso?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nesse caso basta criares uma array usando `let currencies = Object.keys(json.rates);`.
O [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) vai extrair todas a chaves de um objeto e criar uma array com as mesmas.

Ou seja:

```js
const url = 'https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?base=USD'

fetch(url)
  .then(result => result.json())
  .then(json => {
    const currencies = Object.keys(json.rates);
    console.log(currencies);
  })
```